# How can I connect my MySQL database with Cloud JIRA Database?

Tags: mysql, database, jira, jira-rest-api

I am having one asp.net application in which I used MySQL as database. The MySQL database is having the list of Issues in one of the table. I want to access the Database of our Cloud JIRA and want to insert the issues of MySQL DB into the cloud JIRA DB directly from that asp.net application.

Is there any API available for us to do so? What will be the best approach to fulfill the above requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JIRA Cloud, you are not able to access the database at all. It's part of the limitation of Cloud. You might be able to use [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis) depends on what you are looking to achieve exactly.

However, I would recommend you to find a way to export the issues from your ASP.net Application to CSV file and then [restore the CSV file](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/creating-issues-using-the-csv-importer-764478441.html) into your Cloud JIRA since JIRA has an ability to create issues from Excel file.

Note that, you may need to contact Atlassian Support for restoring JIRA from CSV file since they do have full control over instances.

Comment: Hi @Saleh, thanks for your suggestion.

Is this possible to fetch data from MySQL database one by one and import them into cloud JIRA with the help of REST API? We can put an iteration to import issues in bulk. Is this possible?

Comment: Technically you can create new issue via curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://URL:8090/rest/api/2/issue/ . Take a look at https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue for further details example. And of course you can export your issues from your MySQL database :-)

Comment: Thanks :-) - I have gone through with the above URL. I did not any bulk import option in the REST API. Does it support bulk import?

Comment: Well in order to do it in bulk, you have to write up a script :-) REST API doesn't give an direct option for bulk create but it gives an option to create. Thus, maybe you can write up a python script with that to do it in bulk :-)